# Poisson Distribution Overlap

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The arrival of clients in a store is modeled as a poison process with  λ=3  clients per hour.

What is the probability that 3 Clients arrive between 10:00AM-11:00 AM and 3 clients arrive between 10:30 and 11:30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** The question has changed. This is an answer to the current version.

The number of arrivals in the region of overlap is Poisson parameter $1.5$. The event described happens if there are $k$ clients in the region of overlap, and $3-k$ in **each** of the regions $10:00$ to $10:30$ and $11:00$ to $11:30$. The second probability is $\left(e^{-1.5}\frac{(1.5)^{3-k}}{(3-k)!}\right)^2$. So our probability is
$$\sum_{k=0}^3 e^{-1.5}\frac{(1.5)^k}{k!}\left(e^{-1.5}\frac{(1.5)^{3-k}}{(3-k)!}\right)^2.$$
Before evaluating the above expression, we can substantially simplify.

Comment: There was a number missing:What is the probability that 3 Clients arrive between 10:00AM-11:00 AM and 3 clients arrive between 10:30 and 11:30?